# Bootstrap CSS lining up button with input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to line up my buttons next to my inputs and am having trouble in doing so. I am new with bootstrap css and css in general will someone please tell me where I am going wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/5N6FQ/404/

My search and New button are not lining up as I would like it to Any help is greatly appreciated.

What Iv Tried:[image]

What it should look like:[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>

    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <label for="ItemID">ITEM ID</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="ItemID" id="ItemID" /> 
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" name="Search" id="Search" value="Search">
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <label for="Qty">QTY</label>
        <select name="Qty" id="Qty" class="form-control">
            <option value="1" selected>1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
            <option value="18">18</option>
            <option value="19">19</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
        </select>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>

    <div class="col-xs-4">
    <label for="Dealers"></label>
        <select name="Dealers" id="Dealers" class="form-control">
            <option value="" selected></option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" name="New" value="NEW">

</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>

    <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" name="Report" value="REPORT">

    <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" name="PrintLabels" value="PRINT LABELS">

    <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" name="LogItIn" value="LOG IT IN">

    <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" name="CompleteIt" value="COMPLETE IT">

    <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" name="Exit" value="EXIT">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#ItemID, #Search { display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: what about wrapping the input in tables. inside `col-*-*`?

Comment: Hi, Vicki please remove the bootstrap.min.css from External Resources, this fiddle have no sense with this.

Comment: @Vicki Not posting it as an answer. But what I am trying to say is : https://jsfiddle.net/wLhvunue/1/  , You may customize it further as per your requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look at [Input Groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) to add the button to the input field.

```css
#btn-inputs {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <label for="ItemID">ITEM ID</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ItemID" id="ItemID"> <span class="input-group-btn">
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" name="Search" id="Search" value="Search"/>
      </span>

      </div>
      <!-- /input-group -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <label for="Qty">QTY</label>
      <select name="Qty" id="Qty" class="form-control">
        <option value="1" selected>1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="17">17</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <label for="Dealers"></label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <select name="Dealers" id="Dealers" class="form-control">
          <option value="" selected></option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
        </select> <span class="input-group-btn">
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="button"  name="New" value="NEW" />
      </span>

      </div>
      <!-- /input-group -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="btn-inputs">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" name="Report" value="REPORT">
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" name="PrintLabels" value="PRINT LABELS">
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" name="LogItIn" value="LOG IT IN">
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" name="CompleteIt" value="COMPLETE IT">
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" name="Exit" value="EXIT">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you mean; they are on the bottom of the form and centered. Are you referring to the image you have of "what it should look like"?

Comment: Hit the blue "Run code snippet" above and click full page on the right.

Comment: I'll take a look at it as soon as I'm able to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91035/discussion-between-vanburenx-and-vicki).

Answer (score 0):

All elements on the form should be within a col-* class.

For example, the block with your 'New' button should be:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>

    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <label for="Dealers">Dealers</label>
        <select name="Dealers" id="Dealers" class="form-control">
            <option value="" selected></option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <label></label>
      <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" name="New" value="NEW">
    </div>

</div>
```

In this case, ensure you **do not** use the `form-inline` class on your form tag, since it will attempt to push your labels inline with your input fields.

Comment: i edited that block a little to put in "dealer" into the label, and to put a blank label above the New button to get the same spacing. If this doesn't work, let me know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Look this fiddle >> http://jsfiddle.net/kwxm3n9n/

Use col-heading and col-bottom to positioning the same col-*-*(s).

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-9"></div> <<-- left 
  <div class="col-sm-3"><div> <<-- right
</div>
```

And now we can build the rest forms.

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
  <div class="row"></div> <<-- first row (item, search, qty)
  <div class="row"></div> <<-- for select
  <div class="row"></div> <<-- for tables
  <div class="row"></div> <<-- for buttons
</div>
```

Use rows to the same build right side.